# Road and vehicle detection from aerial images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection

I am currently working with MATLAB to detect roads/highways from aerial/satellite images. I have written code for the same basing my concept on intensity differences in value of a road and its surroundings. But the efficiency is not really great as it is detecting non-road entities as well. Along with this I am also going to detect vehicles on these roads and therby try and calculate the width of the road. Can you please assist me in improving my current approach or suggesting a new method?

Thanks in advance! :)

I have attached my MATLAB code for review.

```
clc
clear all
close all

a=rgb2gray(imread('freeway24.tif'));

a2=mean(a);
t=min(a2);

b=lt(a,t);
[row_b, column_b]=size(b);

for i=1:row_b
for j=1:column_b
    if b(i,j)~=1
        b(i,j)=0;
    else
        b(i,j)=255;
    end
end
end

bw0=bwareaopen(b,50);
bw1=bwmorph(bw0,'clean');
bw2=bwmorph(bw1,'majority');
bw3=bwmorph(bw2,'fill');
bw4=imfill(bw3,'holes');

[row_final,column_final]=size(bw4);
bw_final=zeros();
for i=1:row_final
for j=1:column_final
    if bw4(i,j)==1
        bw_final(i,j)=a(i,j);
    else
        bw_final(i,j)=0;
    end
end
end

subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(a);
title('Original Image');
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(bw_final);
title('After detection');
```

Note: As I don't have 10 reputation points, I am unable to post the input image. I have uploaded the link to the image here.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0MIQKh4Irk8MVlXYnhIcmpxTG8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you study more about computer vision, especially these matlab functions: [imclose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html), the [imerode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html), the [imdilate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html), and the [bwareaopen](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html).
A code to help you is presented below. You simply have to add it before the last imshow.

```
% Calculate disk of radius 2 pixels, 4 pixels diameter
se = strel('disk', 2);
% Connect the white pixels that are less than 4 pixels apart
bw_final = imclose(bw_final, se);
% Connect the black pixels that are less than 4 pixels apart
bw_final = ~imclose(~bw_final, se);

% Calculate 2% of the image pixels
num2Percent = round(numel(bw_final)/50);
% Remove white area smaller than 2%
bw_final = bwareaopen(bw_final, num2Percent);
% Remove black area smaller than 2%
bw_final = ~bwareaopen(~bw_final, num2Percent);
```

Comment: Will read up on those surely! Thanks for the help man! But this eliminates the vehicles on the freeway though. I need to detect individual vehicles as blobs so that i can detect their width. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to remove the vehicles, sorry. Simply remove the code line "Remove white area smaller than 2%".  If it helps, please mark as answer and upvote :)

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot! Yes will thumbsup!

Comment: Is there any way to detect these individual detected cars and calculate their properties? Treating them like some sort of blobs?

Comment: bwlabel will associate a number to each white "blob" in the image, so you can decide to analyse only label#3, or label#7... You should find a tutorial about computer vision using Matlab. "http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html".